# Access insert into values

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access

I created a table in Access and the connection works, but my loop through my dataframe using `iterrows()` is throwing a syntax error.

I have tried removing spaces and altering the syntax.

```
for index, row in futures_table.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('''
                    INSERT INTO cme_oil_futures (MONTH,SETTLE,DATE,REPORT_TYPE)
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                ''',(row['MONTH'],row['SETTLE'],row['DATE'],row['REPORT_TYPE']))
    conn.commit()
```

Expected result is to insert the values for each row in the "MONTH", "SETTLE", "DATE", and "REPORT_TYPE" columns from my dataframe.

The error I get is "

> Exception has occurred: pyodbc.ProgrammingError
>   ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)')
>     File "E:\Python\DDWebsraping\cme_oil.py", line 83, in 
>       ''',(row['MONTH'],row['SETTLE'],row['DATE'],row['REPORT_TYPE']))

Comment: why not `futures_table.to_sql()` rather than iteration?

Comment: how do I connect to the access database, just futures_table.to_sql("table", engine, if_exists='append')?

Comment: Is `?` the correct placeholder token?

Comment: @JohnGordon I was wondering that, I checked other questions and it seems to be correct.

Comment: Hmm.  Is `DATE` a reserved word?

Comment: that is what the [pyodbc docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started) says to use '?' as a variable placeholder.

Comment: I tried the same code and removed the row["DATE"] and it has the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. I think you just needed brackets around the fields. MS Access is a strange and mysterious beast.

```
for index, row in futures_table.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('''
                    INSERT INTO cme_oil_futures ([MONTH],[SETTLE],[DATE],[REPORT_TYPE])
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                ''',(row['MONTH'],row['SETTLE'],row['DATE'],row['REPORT_TYPE']))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Using this now gives the following error which seems common: 'Exception has occurred: pyodbc.Error
('HYS22', "[HYS22] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'MONTH'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again. (-1507) (SQLExecDirectW)")'

Comment: FWIW, only `Month` & `Date` need to be enclosed in square brackets, as these are [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) in MS Access.

Comment: How do  reserved words make a database *strange and mysterious beast*?

Comment: It's just my opinion. I think Access's SQL dialect is one of the worst around and I think in general Access makes a lot of decisions I don't agree with. Like, in this case, I'd rather they just not allow someone to make a column named the same as a reserved word. Reserved word should mean reserved! That way we wouldn't need to know esoteric syntax things like having to put brackets around reserved words.